# Typo in a resume?

Tags: resume, hiring-process, job-search, recruitment, internship

I  am a graduating student in college and I recently started hunting for internship jobs as part of our university's academic requirements. I am currently looking for Internships related with IT industry (developer, project manager assistant, quality assurance, etc).


I sent resumes and I accidentally left a typo on my **Seminars Attended** section. Instead of writing *Practicum Preparation Workshop*, I wrote Practicum *Preparaction* Workshop. 

Will this result in my resume getting thrown in the garbage or getting shredded?

Can someone please help me on this matter? Any advice?

Comment: This is not an answerable question. All you can get is the opinions of readers - it's not really possible to answer like this.

Comment: I was hoping for replies whether they were answers or opinions as long as it helps :) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I approach a careless error in a submitted resume/CV that dramatically changes perception?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13470/how-should-i-approach-a-careless-error-in-a-submitted-resume-cv-that-dramaticall)

Comment: Unless you are applying for a job where a super-human level of attention to detail is *essential*, then you have nothing to worry about. Except of course, your tendency to worry.

Comment: @Saudate Well, just an opinion as we cannot predict whatever goes through the minds of whoever receives your CV. 
First of all, many people will not notice.
Now, most people who do notice it - will think it is a typo. 
Just a handful of very detail-oriented folks will actually make a big deal out of it, and trust me, you don't want to work for them :) 
Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is this important?**

A CV communicates a lot of information about you. Not only factual information, but also:

- Are you a good writer? Do you know the STAR technique?
- Do you pay attention to layout?
- Do you pay attention to detail? Are there any typo's?
- What language are you comfortable with? Did you provide multiple versions in different languages?

**What are the consequences of a typo?**

A typo in your CV shows that you did not pay attention to detail.

- You will be less likely to be invited when applying for a job where being detail-oriented is essential, like proofreading newspaper articles. **This is not bad, as you would not be the right person for this type of job anyway.**
- If you mentioned 'detail-oriented' or 'perfectionist' on your resume, the other self-described facts on your resume will be looked at with equal suspicion. I already saw CV's where the person said he/she was a `perfetctionist`...

**What should I do now?**

Both these consequences are minor at best. So fix the typo in all subsequent CVs you sent out. Also check whether you can upload a new version to online recruitment platforms.

And, if you mentioned 'detail-oriented' on your CV, be prepared that the interviewer will need a little more convincing of that :-)

Comment: I had a huge typo on mine on my skills list and it appears that only 2 out 10 company I apply for mention it at the interview, nobody read carefully resume.

Comment: Just because 1/5 mentioned it, does not mean they did not see it. I will never mention a typo, but it does influence my view of the candidate. I will probably gently prod whether the candidate reviews a document before sending it out, or often does things last-minute.

Answer (score -1):

First off, go in and change it so its not messed up for the jobs you apply to from here on out.

Second, there really is nothing you can do here. On one hand many resumes get parsed electronically for key words and things like GPA etc. in this regard you are fine as it will just overlook that.

I can only speak personally here but I am in charge of recruitment for my team at work and I will say this. I am a terrible speller and most likely would not have seen that mistake at first or even second glance. That being said I know may people that would have seen that and been a bit offended by it. The truth is its all about the person that sees it, yes it may end up in the garbage, they may not care or they may ask you about it during an interview to try and see how you act in a situation where you know you made a mistake.

I would not get too worried about it, it seems like a less obvious spelling error anyway.