# I have a big mistake on my resume and I already sent it out

Tags: resume

By mistake I don't mean a typo. See I am a graphic designer so I made my resume in Indesign so I could put my personal logo on it. However, I didn't notice that for some reason there is a green square on my resume and I have no idea how it got there. (my logo isn't green nor does it have squares.)

I already sent this resume out to some companies...including a really well known company. I thought I might have a shot at this job and now I am so embarrassed if that was the resume the recruiters sent to them. A minor typo could be overlooked, but a green square on my resume is noticeable.

Comment: @JanDoggen I don't think this is a duplicate. In that question, OP's "mistake" was an incorrect education qualification, which could be a serious issue. This "green square" mistake definitely isn't anywhere close to it.

Comment: @happy I was doubtful as well, and also did not know which of the many [duplicate candidates](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+error+resume) to choose from. Since she is a graphics designer and calls it 'big' herself I assumed some graphics artifact is 'on the same level' as a content error.

Comment: @JanDoggen I too vaguely recall having seen a similar question a few months ago. However, on the duplicate question, the candidate will fail a background check if she does nothing, which can lead to blacklisting and stuff. In this case, the worst scenario is she won't get an interview call. The other question you found (http://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/13470/3192) is perhaps a "better" duplicate candidate.

Answer (score 5):

Your best option is to do nothing.

Don't even start thinking of sending them a "corrected" resume. That would be the equivalent of dousing fire with gasoline (or petrol, if you prefer British English).

You see the green square as a huge mistake because you are only working with your own resume, and it occupies a significant part of your "mind space". The person reading your resume reads dozens of resume per day, and isn't aware of the "significance" of the green square, and hence, would most likely not think much of it. Pointing out the green square ensures that they pay more attention to your "mistake" rather than the rest of your resume.

See also: [Streisand Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect)

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything you can do at this stage.  You've already sent it out.  If it is brought up on any interviews you have, then have a pre-planned short and consist answer to deal with that and move on.  At that juncture your job is to control the conversation and move it onto another selling point about you - after all, it is your interview.

McKayla Maroney said it best when she said this memorable quote; ***"Looking back isn't going to help you. Moving forward is the thing you have to do."***

So allow your focus to be on the good points of your resume and not the bad ones.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

How you correct your resume/CV depends on how it was submitted.

In many companies the website where you apply for jobs do allow you to change the resume or cover letter after you apply. Now it doesn't mean that they haven't already read it, but there is no harm uploading the corrected version.

It is likely that when a person reads the resume to prepare for the interview they will download a fresh copy of the resume.